# Equivalent of mysql date function in mongo?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

How can I write the below SQL query in Mongo?

```
select * from test where date(created)=curdate()
```

N.B created is a datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this with MongoDB is to simply use a range query with externally calculated dates. So if you were working with the current date and wanted all items in that current day:

```js
var start = new Date();
start = new Date( start.valueOf() - start.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );
end  = new Date( start.valueOf() + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );

db.collection.find({ "created": { "$gte": start, "$lt": end } });
```

So the [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators define the range of dates to search from the values you calculated or otherwise supplied. The approach is the same for other languages which will all have a date object "type" that serializes to the BSON required by your driver. Check your driver documentation for details.

You can do essentially that query using the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator that evaluates JavaScript, but this is not recommended. The reason being that the "range" form already given can make use of an index to reduce the items scanned, where as a JavaScript evaluation cannot:

```js
db.collection.find(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    today = new Date( today.valueOf() - today.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) );

    return ( 
        ( this.created.valueOf() - this.created.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) )
        == today.valueOf()
   );
})
```

That is essentially the equivalent of the SQL statement, but it is not as efficient as the first form as an index cannot be used to evaluate. The same could be said for the SQL.

So use the range query version instead as it is better, and try to avoid JavaScript evaluation where possible.

You can find more information on common SQL statements in MongoDB terms within the manual:

- [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)
- [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)